# define a fuction that print something at breakpoint in gdb

Tags: gdb

I know `b` and `command` can print things when breakpoint triggers. But in my program, there're lots of `memcpy`, I need to print the `target length` and `source address` when code goes there, which are register `$r2` and `$r1`.

The `memcpy`s are located at:

```
$my_module_base+0xaaa
$my_module_base+0xbbb
...
```

I tried to write a function that take the `$my_module_base` as argument and set these breakpoint automatically

```
define set_all_bp
    set $module_base=$arg0

    b *$module_base+0xaaa
    command
        echo Here is memcpy 1:\n
        my_dump $r1 $r2
    end

    b *$module_base+0xbbb
    command
        echo Here is memcpy 2:\n
        my_dump $r1 $r2
    end
end
```

But it doesn't work, gdb says:

```
(gdb) source my_script
bp:8: Error in sourced command file:
This command cannot be used at the top level.
(gdb)
```

Any other way to do this?